# How do I add another validation function to an html button using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have to use a user control form

In that form, there is a `Submit` button.

That button is `html` button.

That button has lots of validation functions for the other controls.

Now I want to add another function of my own into that button.

Now I faced my problem. I dunno the ID of that button.

When I `view source` I find no ID or Name.

But I can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
     $("input[type=submit]").click(function () { return validateCaptcha(); })
</script>
```

To add my  function.

If I do that, only my function would run and the other original validation functions are not running anymore.

I want to append my function at the end of its validation functions.

I found this..

[JavaScript: Adding an onClick handler without overwriting the existing one from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891989/javascript-adding-an-onclick-handler-without-overwriting-the-existing-one)

But that one find the controls by `tagname`. If I find it by `tagname` there would be lots of `input` tags.

Is there any other way to combine the 2 answers that I found?

Tkz

Comment: if validateCaptcha returns false or preventsDefault it will prevent the event from bubbling to other handlers.  Other than that, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name or the ID of the form you are working on you could do

```
$("#formname").submit(function(){return validateCaptcha(); });
```

or

```
$("form[name=form_name]").submit(function(){return validateCaptcha();});
```

Witout knowing the ID of the submit button or the form (or the name of either) it would be difficult to validate; you need some sort of identifier.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have any id or name there is no way to distinguish control from others in page.
So, simple solution will be to give id to button placed in user control. And in javascript if placed inside that page you can access it unique Id using ClientID. e.g.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnOK" Text="Send Me" />
```

In JS Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
   $("#<%= btnOK.ClientID%>").click(function () { return validateCaptcha(); })
</script>
```

Comment: I can't touch the ascx. That's why

Comment: you can do that by accessing that control in containing page too. e.g.                             
     this.FindControl("userControl").FindControl("btnOK").ClientID

Answer (score 0):

If it has a class you can also do like this

```
$(".className").click(function () { return validateCaptcha(); })
```

or find any other unique attribute of that button.

```
$("input[uniqueAttribute='uniqueAttributeValue']").click(function () { return validateCaptcha(); })
```

by doing this kind of selector, make sure the selector results to only 1.