# jQuery: Does adding an event listener overwrite the previous listener of the same event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, let's say I have

```
$(element).on('click', function() {/*Some Stuff*/});
```

defined somewhere, then later I want to add more features to that same click event. If I do

```
$(element).on('click', function() {/*Other Stuff*/});
```

will "Other Stuff" overwrite "Some Stuff"?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891989/javascript-adding-an-onclick-handler-without-overwriting-the-existing-one

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is clear and concise.

Comment: Lol, I didn't want to blindly write code without knowing if this was the case. I edited my question to make more sense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The second listener won't override the first. jQuery event handlers are added cumulatively and execute in the order they were attached.

The thing that does effect whether one handler prevents the other running is how the function cancels the browser's default click handler (i.e. how you stop the browser following the link's url)

If you use traditional method:

```
$(element).on('click', function() {

    /* Some Stuff, do your thing */ 

    return false; 
});
```

The handler above will stop the event itself and propagating to other handlers.

But you can stop the event action without stopping its propagation or the handler:

```
$(element).on('click', function(e) {

    // prevent the default action at first, just to make it clear :)
    e.preventDefault(); 

    /* do your thing */

    return /* what you want */;
});
```

This will ensure that the default click action doesn't occur but that the event continues to other hanlders. jQuery event also has some other useful [event propagation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) (e.g. `Event.stopPropagation()`) which are worth getting to know.

Comment: Oh! That explains it. I always wondered why bother using .preventDefault()... Now I know.

Comment: What if you're adding the exact same callback twice? for example: `jQuery(window).on("scroll, MyClass.scroll")`. Is there a test for that? (I suppose I could look. Sigh.)

Answer (score 14):

No, the events are not overwritten, they are appended or pushed to the list of event handlers.

This is a typical usage of the [observer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005300/example-of-javascript-observer-pattern).

Events can be removed with http://api.jquery.com/off/ or http://api.jquery.com/die/ in case `.live` was used.

Answer (score 5):

This has been already been answered but I thought I'd add how I usually address this problem when I am in a situation where I might have a click listener getting duplicated.

I just user query *on* and *off* methods...

> $(element).off('click'); //Removes a previously added click listener using the ***on*** method
>
> $(element).on('click', function() {/*Some Stuff*/}); //Adds it back and only runs once

http://api.jquery.com/off/

> The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on(). See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on that page for more information. Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. It just gives a suggested technique. The question was already clearly answered. In this question game you typically either answer the question in a new way or call out that you are providing additional information that was not already provided, if you want the upvotes.

Comment: good point Josh, I wasn't looking for any ranking. I just stumbled across this as I was researching this issue and thought other people might want to know as well...

Comment: Understood. I only posted a comment since you seem new to the site.

Comment: This was extremely helpful Matthew. This technique enabled me to solve an issue whereby many vanilla JS event listeners were stacking. Much gratitude to you!

Answer (score 4):

No it won't. `on()` is just like bind--it adds the event to `$.data("events")`

You can explicitly remove stuff via `off()` though.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood; adding another handler does not overwrite the first.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymuBs/

Clicking on the link writes "one" to the console. Clicking the button adds another handler to the link. Now clicking the link writes "one" and "two" to the console: